# How do I set the Allow Nulls property in table designer of SSMS to be always false?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio when creating a New Table or adding columns to an existing table through the Table Designer, there are 3 columns presented:

1. Column Name
2. Data Type
3. Allow Nulls

Allow Nulls always defaults to `True` (ticked), however, I am wondering if it is possible to configure SSMS to always default this to `False` (unticked)?

To a lesser extent I am also interested to know if it is possible to configure the editable default options within the Column Properties tab in the lower pane.

Comment: I suggest staying away from the table designer. Using proper DDL is much easier to script, reproduce, store in source control, and also avoids many unresolved bugs or quirks in the visual designers.

Comment: I had a look through the SSMS registry and various xml files in the SSMS directory and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are fine with manipulating the registry key, here is an option to force the SSMS to always assign the value *false* to *Allow Null* property.

#### `NOTE: Please be careful while altering registry keys.`

1. Type *regedit* in the *Windows Start* --> *Run* command to open the Registry Editor.
2. Navigate to **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\DataProject`** You might need to change the SQL Server version accordingly. I am using *SQL Server 2008 R2 Express* and hence the version *100*.
3. Under the above mentioned registry path, look for the key name **`SSVDefaultAllowNull`**.
4. Right-click on the key and select *Modify* option. Change the value from *1* to **`0`**. Default value is *1*, which represents *True*.
5. If you are already running *SQL Server Management Studio*, restart it. Thanks to [@Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m) for pointing out this step.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well done on digging that up! I'll have to watch carefully now if I decide to use an interactive mode to create tables. :) A possible Step #5: If SSMS is running while you are changing the property, you'll need to restart it for the new setting to take effect.

Comment: @Siva - thank you - great find. As I'm sure everyone who's following this question has noticed there's lot's of other interesting configuration there too.

Comment: May I add a subsequent question....  I would like to add the description property to the new table designer.....   can you assist in pointing me in the correct direction?   I will post another question on SO for all to see as well.   thanks

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I am not exactly sure whether the default value for *Allow Nulls* is configurable or not. I expect it is not. In fact, I hope it will not be configurable, as it might be confusing at some times. Here's my reasoning.

Defaulting *Allow Nulls* to `True` seems to me consistent with defaulting the absence of `NULL`/`NOT NULL` in a column declaration of a DDL statement to `NULL`. That is, whether I omit that bit of column definition when using a `CREATE TABLE` statement or I don't pay attention to it when using a dialogue mode of some tool like SSMS, I would expect the outcome to be the same.

Since the absence of `NULL` or `NOT NULL` have been interpreted as `NULL` by many people for quite some time already, I don't think it would make much sense to change that meaning now. And consequently, the default value for the *Allow Nulls* option in a New Table dialogue shouldn't be changed either.

What *might* make sense, though, is a *Default new columns to Deny Null* switch (turned off initially, of course) in the dialogue box to change the default behaviour in this particular session of table editing.

Comment: +1 - It's a reflection of the normal behavior experienced when creating a table with a script - if you don't specify anything, `NULL` is allowed.

Comment: @Andriy M - thank you personally for following/commenting this question and answers.

Comment: @Barry Kaye: Not at all, I was too hasty in laying out my concerns about possible confusions the (then) potential switch might cause, so it only remained for me to follow this thread and be equally honest on others' finds.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine it is not configurable, just because of the fits that SSMS throws when you try to turn it off in edit table mode (assuming they use the same underlying code base).

However, you may be able to achieve what you want using [SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx).  This will override default nullability of new columns (for the session).

Note the difference in the "Nullable" column in sp_help with the below query.

```
set ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON
create table test (id int)
go
sp_help test
go
set ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON OFF

drop table test
create table test (id int)
go
sp_help test
```

I am assuming that you want to do this to enforce yourself or people you work with to default their columns as NOT NULL instead of NULL.

Comment: Interesting, didn't realise there was such a setting! I wonder if SSMS reads it when you call the table design pane. I guess one could find that out, if there was a way to inject this command into the session SSMS uses for table editing, just prior to opening the table design pane.

Comment: That was my original thought, the table creation screen did not seem to respond to the change in this setting.  I meant to write that, my bad.

Comment: That screen might be using its own session, so, if you tried to change the setting in a query window and then call the New Table command, I think it was all right that you could not see the effect.

Comment: @Jeremy Gray - thanks - certainly an interesting approach/attempt. Re: your assumption - no conspiracies - I simply find the majority of my database columns tend to be NOT NULL and thought it would be fractionally easier not to have to un-tick the checkbox!